# Eigenstates and eigenvalues

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

We define two operators:

A = $i (p/\sqrt(2)) + W(x)$ and $A^+ = - i (p/\sqrt(2)) + W(x)$.

And two Hamiltonian operators:

$H_{-} = AA^+ $, and $H_{+} = A^+A$.

Show that if $|n^- >$ is a normed eigenstate for $H_{-}$ with the eigenvalue $E_n$, then $A|n^->$ is the eigenstate for $H_{+}$ with the same eigenvalue.

How do I go forward here?

Comment: You need to wrap Mathjax in dollar signs (for inline math) or double dollars (for math on it's own line).  It will not display properly without this.  See [Mathjax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that $H_{-} |n^{-} \rangle = E_n |n^{-} \rangle $ you need to show that

$H_{+} A |n^{-} \rangle = E_n |n^{-} \rangle$

Hint: Use the fact that $H_{-}$ and $H_{+}$ commute and a little algebra.